# Rendering multiple Pandas' dataframes from concatenated JSON strings based upon user inpu

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, flask

I am trying to display charts in a Flask webapp built upon Jinja templates based upon a pandas dataframe that is filtered by a value the user specifies.

In my file for this specific page I have the following:

```
<form>
        <div id="radio">

                <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="Values"checked="checked" value="Value1"><label for="radio1">Value1</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="Values" value="Value2"><label for="radio2">Value2</label>

                <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="Values"value="Value3"><label for="radio3">Value3</label>
                <a href='#' id="branch_input"><button type="button">Submit</button> </a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

For the radio buttons the user will chose from. 
In my base template I have the following which is I think what I need to get at the value:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function) {
              $('a#valueinput_input').bind('click',function() {
                  $.getJSON('/_filterandreturndataframes',{
                      Values: $('input[name="Values"]:checked').val(),
                  }, function(data) {
                      <!--"confused"-->
                  }
              }

          }

      </script>
```

Which I would then pass onto Python something like

```
@app.route('_filterandreturndataframes')
def
    filtervalue = request.args.get('Values')
    #filtering and compiling dataframes here
    data = dataframe1.to_json() OR .to_html()?
    data2 = dataframe2.to_json() OR .to_html()?
    return data, data2
```

Python, if I understand correctly, can return multiple values from one function. JavaScript, if I am understand it correctly, can only return one. I would prefer to have the user click one button and get two graphs outputted in the web page. I have figured out how to get a JSON string from each dataframe using .to_json() but have no clue how to combine them into one array of JSON strings (or if even that's the right way to go about this) and then parse that array into the relevant strings for output to tables attached to specific paragraph ids. Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `to_json()` you end up with two string types.  You could just create your own JSON string?

```
'[' + ','.join([data, data2]) + ']'
```

Another clunky way would be to just use python `list`s and `dict`s as intermediate data structures, then use the json module to serialize it into json since python `list`s and `dict`s interact nicely with the json module.

```
import json

l1 = dataframe1.to_dict(orient='records')
l2 = dataframe2.to_dict(orient='records')
D = {'data1' : l1, 'data2' : l2}
jsonstr = json.dumps(D)
```

If you don't care for mixing the two datasets, you could also concat the two dataframes, then spit out one giant dataframe as json.

Comment: Thanks! The next question then is: once the dataframe-combo is in the webpage, how do I split them up again and then pass them to specific IDs? Or Jinja variables? As tables?